# Enumerate inner elements with xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

I have xml file with such structure:

```
...
<outer>
   ...
   <inner/>
   ...
</outer>
...
<outer>
   ...
   <inner/>
   ...
</outer>
...
```

Instead of "..." there exist other elements. How one could enumerate `<inner/>` elements using `xslt`? The output should be:

```
...
<outer>
   ...
   <inner>1</inner>
   ...
</outer>
...
<outer>
   ...
   <inner>2</inner>
   ...
</outer>
...
```

**EDIT 1.**
What if we need to count and copy only `<outer copy="1">`?
This doesn't work:

Comment: <xsl:template match="outer[@copy="1"]/inner"> doesn't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `xsl:number`:

```
<xsl:stylesheet
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="1.0">

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="outer/inner">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:number level="any"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: found <xsl:number count="outer[@copy="1"]/inner" level="any"/>

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you are looking for:

> ```
> <xsl:for-each select="outer/inner">
>
> </xsl:for-each>
> ```